# Пропадает интернет при подключении ОВЕН СПК110

Tags: сеть, windows-7

В общем, есть ПК и есть "ОВЕН СПК110 Программируемый панельный контроллер". При подключении его к ПК появляется новое подключение со своими айпишниками и шлюзом, при этом интернет то работает, то не работает. Интернет идёт с сетевой карты, которая подключена к Микротику. Можно ли как-то решить эту траблу, может прописав маршруты? Windows 7.

Сеть от сетевухи: 192.168.1.143
255.255.255.0
192.168.1.1

Сеть СПК: 10.0.20.100
255.255.0.0
10.0.6.10

Answer (score 1):

> При подключении его к ПК появляется новое подключение со своими айпишниками **и шлюзом**

В этом и ошибка - дефолтный шлюз должен быть только один, через сетевую карту в Инет. Следует его удалить и добавить вместо него  (если это необходимо) частный маршрут в конкретную (под)сеть.